# crontab @reboot does not execute bash script when server is rebooted

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm using `@reboot ~/www/example.com/bin/server` in my user's crontab...but when I reboot the server, the web server (this script) does not come up. (script works fine from command line).

My guess is the `/home/user` directory has not been mounted yet...does anyone know if its possible to get a script to run out of a home directory using this `crontab @reboot` method?

Comment: One common problem with running commands from CRON is that the environment is not identical to that in a login shell. Often, one easy way to fix this is to write a little bash script that sources e.g. ~/.bashrc and then calls the desired program and put the call to this script into the CRON table. The other question is however: What is the specific reason to start something as complex as a web server from a CRON job? Why not use the init services?

Comment: As per the comment of @MarcusRickert , try indicating the whole path of the script instead of `~`.

Comment: whole path didn't work either.

Comment: I'd recommend using `$HOME` instead of `~` to refer to your home directory.  A variable like that will certainly be populated by the shell, but expansion of tildes is less predictable.

Comment: Also note that the shell used by cron may not be bash. It could be dash or ash in some systems. That could cause problems if you use something unique to bash. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the crontab did not have a full environment. I made the script it was pointing to source my `.bashrc`.

```
@reboot /home/user/www/example.com/bin/server
```

`./server` does `. /home/user/.bashrc` to get a working environment.

Answer (score 7):

If you think /home/user hasn't been mounted (or some required systems aren't running) yet, in your crontab line, you can always wait before executing a command like:

`@reboot sleep 60; /home/user/www/example.com/bin/server`

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely be due to the environment scenarios as given in comments. Try the following and check once by doing a reboot

```
@reboot (date > /tmp/date-check.txt)
```

To be sure cron is able to run the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu if you are using the Home Directory Encryption feature turned on then @reboot in your crontab file won't work as the file system is still encrypted when the system is starting up and cron runs its @reboot jobs.

Your options are to place your files in an unencrypted location (`/usr/local/bin` or something?) or disable Home Directory encryption on your home directory.